# How to get the CloudFront distribution's domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

The goal is to create a custom domain for my Serverless api: `api.example.com`.
So my approach is to create this Route53 record:

```
ApiDomainRecord:
  Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
  Properties:
    Type: A
    Name: api.example.com
    HostedZoneId: Z2PERRPAZRTJGB
    AliasTarget:
      HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
      DNSName:
        Fn::GetAtt: [ --> what do we enter here <--, DomainName ]
```

But how do I provide the domain name from the CloudFront emitted by Serverless?

Comment: Is your CloudFront distribution created in cloud formation?

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran I'm talking about the cloudfront implicitly created with api gateway.. not sure if it has a different name

Comment: You cannot get attributes of an existing resource, if it is created already, you can pass it as a parameters and call it using !Ref `DNSName: !Ref CloudfrontDist` or just hardcode the distribution URL.

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran well, the thing is, it is created by the Serverless framework, but I don't see it exposed in [their documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources/)

Comment: https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-api-gateway-domain/

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran yeah, went through it, it's not completely declarative solution. It needs us to run a command at some point in the process. I want a completely declarative solution, that's why i'm turning to CloudFormation.

Comment: I guess, you can create it part of the resources in serverless.yml, here is an example I found from google https://github.com/s0enke/weekly2pocket/blob/master/server/serverless.yml

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran nah, that's just for the static website bucket. Thanx for your efforts by the way :}

Answer (score 2):

**Getting the API Gateway URL**

The only way I've found to get my hands on the API Gateway URL in my *Serverless* templates is to piece it together myself.  I'm certainly [not the first](http://www.goingserverless.com/blog/api-gateway-url) to do it this way.

The API created by serverless is called `ApiGatewayRestApi`.  Since your template is aware of the region and stage, you can piece together the URL like so:

```
      DNSName:
        Fn::Join:
          - ""
          - - "https://"
            - Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
            - ".execute-api.${self:provider.region}.amazonaws.com/${self:provider.stage}"
```

---

**Unfortunately, this won't work**

Although I believe API Gateway uses CloudFront under the hood (at least for edge optimized endpoints), plugging the above code into your script will result in an error, complaining that the hosted zone is wrong for this URL.  This is unsurprising, since `...execute-api...amazonaws.com` is clearly not a subdomain of `cloudfront.net`.

I think you have to use API Gateway's [custom domain feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) to pull this off.  When you create one, you get a real CloudFront URL back that you can use with the CloudFront hosted zone (Z2FDTNDATAQYW2).

The downside of this is that you get a CloudFront distribution created for your API.  This implies that deploying a brand new API is going to take ~20-30 minutes, rather than just a minute or two.

---

**Without a plugin**

In your serverless template, this means creating an [API Gateway `DomainName`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-domainname.html) (and probably a `BasePathMapping`), in addition to the Route 53 `RecordSet`:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    ApiDomainRecord:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
      Properties:
        CertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:<AWS_ACCOUNT>:certificate/3XXXXXXX-2XXX-4XXX-8XXX-8XXXXXXXXXXX
        DomainName: api.example.com
    ApiDomainMapping:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
      Properties:
        BasePath: r53
        DomainName: api.example.com
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
    ApiDNSRecord:
      Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
      Properties:
        Type: A
        Name: api.example.com
        HostedZoneId: ZXXXXXXXXXXXXXA
        AliasTarget:
          HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
          DNSName:
            Fn::GetAtt: [ApiDomainRecord, DistributionDomainName]
```

In this example I hit my API at `api.example.com/r53/<STAGE>/<API_RESOURCE>`.  My certificate is for `*.example.com`.  You can also specify stage in the [BasePathMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-basepathmapping.html), if you don't want it in the URL.

---

**With a plugin**

This is a fair amount of boilerplate, and I ***hate*** hard coding ARNs into my templates (the certificate, in this case).

The [`serverless-domain-manager` plugin](https://github.com/amplify-education/serverless-domain-manager) (recommended [here](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-api-gateway-domain/)) can make this less cumbersome.  Not only does it reduce the amount of boilerplate you write, it allows you to specify certificate *name*, rather than ARN.  I had no trouble making it work the first time I tried it.

Using this plugin, the CloudFormation above can be replaced by a short stanza in the `custom` section of your template:

```
custom:
  customDomain:
    domainName: api.example.com
    basePath: r53
    certificateName: "*.example.com"
    createRoute53Record: true
```

Comment: Such a great answer! Thanks.